# HTTP Connector in Microsoft Power Automate - Login against Azure AD app registration on behalf of user not working

Tags: http, azure-active-directory, power-automate, connector, auth0-delegated-admin

I hope you are doing fine :)

I have the following problem/problems.

I have created a dummy (robot) user. In Azure AD there is an App Registration with some Power BI delegated permission services.

I want to automate the deletion of a push dataset via a HTTP request.

For this, I need to authenticate against that App Registration from Azure AD. With postman, everything worked perfectly, I got the token as a response.

Then, I tried to make the same request using the HTTP connector in PowerAutomate.

I get the following error

{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: e6d68953-ce1c-4217-856c-ae3aada82e00\r\nCorrelation ID: f50db4d9-d5bb-4396-af11-214717721f43\r\nTimestamp: 2022-10-26 19:12:48Z","error_codes":[900144],"timestamp":"2022-10-26 19:12:48Z","trace_id":"e6d68953-ce1c-4217-856c-ae3aada82e00","correlation_id":"f50db4d9-d5bb-4396-af11-214717721f43","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=900144"}

The connector looks like this->  [image]

I have tried other ways as well.

The following error ->

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password.\r\nTrace ID: fec65949-0701-4727-af3b-2c2b8eb73a00\r\nCorrelation ID: 42c6c04b-98be-477d-8d36-52a01a473a40\r\nTimestamp: 2022-10-26 19:23:50Z","error_codes":[50126],"timestamp":"2022-10-26 19:23:50Z","trace_id":"fec65949-0701-4727-af3b-2c2b8eb73a00","correlation_id":"42c6c04b-98be-477d-8d36-52a01a473a40","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50126"}

I get from the the next HTTP connector inputs. I tried creating a query out of the previous json. It says the username or password are invalid but I logged in successfully for a number of times with those exact credentials. That I am sure of.

[image]

The dummy inputs in the picture are used to avoid the real ids, username and password.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me ...

[image: HTTP]

Add a header setting `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and add the URL form encoded content string like thus ...

```
client_id=<CLIENT_ID>c&grant_type=password&username=<USERNAME>&password=<PASSWORD>&scope=User.read
```

If you're using the **password** grant type approach, you shouldn't need a client secret, just the client ID.